# Restore single Public Folder item from a "Notes" folder

Tags: exchange-2016, public-folders

I have a public folder that contains "Notes" type items on my Exchange 2016 server.  A user inadvertently deleted one of those notes.

Mail type folders have the option to "Recover Deleted items" in Outlook, but Notes type folders do not.

Does anyone know an easy way to just pull this item out of the Deleted Items?  I have retention turned on, and we are well within the retention period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself, courtesy of this link:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exovoice/2016/11/23/public-folders-data-recovery-scenarios/

1. Download MFCMAPI (the version that matches your Outlook version, 32 or 64 bit)
2. Enable the options "Use the MDB_ONLINE flag when calling OpenMsgStore" and "Use the MAPI_NO_CACHE flag when calling OpenEntry"
3. Click "Session->Logon" and choose the correct Outlook Profile that allows access to the public folder.
4. Double click "Public Folders" and navigate to the folder where the item was deleted from.
5. Right click on the folder and select "Other Tables->Deleted contents".
6. Find the item in question, right click on it and choose Copy.  Then navigate back to the public folder hierarchy and right click and choose Paste.

This solution will work on Calendar Items that were inadvertently deleted as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you restore ‘note’ folder have some error messages? What it says?

If the error message is mentioned in this article, then it is the official article acknowledging the issue.["Outlook was unable to recover some or all of the items in this folder" error when you try to recover deleted items](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/-outlook-was-unable-to-recover-some-or-all-of-the-items-in-this-folder-error-when-you-try-to-recover-deleted-items-cd2c9bf0-0500-456c-bd16-f65b1c2d5233)

If not, you can follow steps mentioned in the [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Exchange-Team-Blog/Recovering-Public-Folders-After-Accidental-Deletion-Part-1/ba-p/601839) to restore public folder.

Comment: That doesn't apply... that is for Exchange 2010 which uses public folder databases, not 2016 which uses public folder MAILBOXES.

There is no error message, because the right click option "Recover Deleted Items" is not even there for a folder of Notes items.  It is there for folders of "Mail" and "post" items, but not for notes folders.